# JS getBoundingClientRect on a nested hidden element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element which is hidden, and a child element inside

```
<element>
   <nested>Hello!<nested>
</element>
```

When `element` is hidden, I get all zero values for

```
nested.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Is there a way to get the real rect values of `nested`, when `element` is hidden, **without** having to first display the parent element

Comment: what do you mean by hidden ? `display: none` ? Then the real rect values are all zero. Otherwise, you should get values. (`display:none` makes it like the element is not part of the document for the renderer, so all his children are also removed)

Comment: Invisible elements do not have readable dimensions. You could clone your element and place it outside the viewport, read the dimensions from there.

Comment: @Fyntasia cloning the element and rendering it elsewhere could work, although in a more complex situation that might easily lead to "wrong" values, if the element’s formatting depends heavily on the DOM structure it is nested in.

Comment: This is true @Cbroe, It's just a solution to this problem that could help OP out.